# How to open multiple windows at a same time in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I want to open 2 salesfroce reports at a same time when clicking on a custom formula field. I used hyperlink function in my formula field but in that i call my Visualforce page and that i will redirect to the method of apex class

Formula field:

```
       HYPERLINK("/apex/leadreport?website=" & Website, "Find Competitors in Database", "_blank")
```

Apex Class:

```
    public PageReference redirectToLeadReport(){

    // Get the Results from
    pageReference pg = new pageReference('https://ap1.salesforce.com/00O90000001wiUo?pv0='+websites  );
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg; 
    }
```

Visualforce page:

```
   <apex:page action="{!redirectToLeadReport}" controller="leadReportController" >
   </apex:page>
```

If any body aware of this so can you please help me.

Thanks,
Kanupriya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could open two windows with one link is to use some javascript, which you won't be able to do (with ease, if at all) from a formula field. That said, you could use some javascript when your Visualforce page loads to then open up the other window you need:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.open("http://url-to-open");
}
```

[This page has some useful information on window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml).

**Edit**

I've just done some experimentation using sorenkrabbe's suggestion, and it does work, the only hitch is that you either end up with one extra tab for the javascript if you use "_blank" as the target, or your leave your current page if you use "_self" as the target. This can be solved by using window.close() to close the newly opened window for the script:

HYPERLINK("javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com?q=window1'); window.open('http://www.google.com?q=window2'); window.close();", 'Open The Windows!' , '_blank')

Comment: I'd say could execute JS from a formula field by defining a formula i line with this: 

HYPERLINK("javascript:window.open('http://google.com?q=window1'); window.open('http://google.com?q=window2');", "Execute JS to open two windows")

Comment: Thanks Guys, for the reply. I already use this option but the problem with this "HYPERLINK("javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com?q=window1'); window.open('http://www.google.com?q=window2'); window.close();", 'Open The Windows!' , '_blank')" is its nt taking my field value which i hv 2 create dynamically. like:  instead of window1 i wanna use my custom field .

Comment: Can't you just reference your fields in the formula?